# The following parameters must be valid date and format (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz): date_of_expiration

Tags: php, data

Olá.

Eu estou criando um sistema de pagamento via pagseguro, onde esse sistema não está deixando criar boletos, pois reclama da data.

Eu sei que a data no estilo `2020-05-30T21:52:49.000-04:00`funciona, mas `date('Y-m-dH:i:s.uZ', strtotime($data. '+ 3 days'));`

Como gerar data nesse modelo que falei que funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi, está faltando o 'T' no seu código. Além disso, pela [documentação](https://m.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/formatacao-de-datas.html?_rnt=dd#!rmcl) do pagseguro eles utilizam a fração de segundos com 3 casas, para isso você deve utilizar 'v' no formato e para o fuso horário, deve-se usar 'P'. [Ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Dessa forma, acredito que deve funcionar:

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP', strtotime($data. '+ 3 days'));
```

Lembrando que `\T` coloca o T como carácter extra e o `Z`, pela [documentação](https://m.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/formatacao-de-datas.html?_rnt=dd#!rmcl) do pagseguro, é opcional.

Tomar cuidado com a utilização `do date('c', ...)` pois mesmo esse convertendo para a `ISO 8601` ( o mesmo que o pagseguro diz aceitar ), o milisegundos tem mais de 4 casas decimais.

Comment: Dessa forma continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Tenta dessa forma então: `date('c', strtotime($data. '+ 3 days'));`. Dessa forma, a data ficaria no padrão  ISO 8601, a mesma que o pagseguro usa. Se funcionar, me avisa para eu editar a resposta de uma forma mais completa.

Comment: funcionou não: 2020-05-29T21:29:06-03:00 a minha que foi gerada e 2020-05-30T21:52:49.000-04:00 e a que funciona, falta milisegundos parece

Comment: Realmente, pelo que eu to lendo sobre, esse formato do PHP não é exatamente igual a iso. Tenta `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP`

Comment: tb n kkkkkkkkk, não estou entendo como o mercadopago quer que envie essa data

Comment: tenta Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP  considerando que a documentação que eu linkei está errada/desatualizada e é obrigatório o fuso horario. Dessa forma, a saida é exatamente igual a 2020-05-30T21:52:49.000-04:00

Comment: boa, funcionou, abigo

Comment: gloria, mais tarde eu edito a resposta original com mais detalhes